# How to configure in IdeaVIM Ctrl + N and Ctrl + P completion from Vim?

Tags: intellij-idea, vim, jetbrains-ide, ideavim

In Vim we can use `Ctrl + N` or `Ctrl + P` to finish code completion. How to configure it in IdeaVim for IntelliJ?

Answer (score 41, accepted):

`Alt + /` and `Alt + Shift + /` work both in plain IntelliJ and with IdeaVim installed.

Please see [documentation](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/idea/auto-completing-code.html#hippie_completion) on JetBrains page - it's called *Hippie Completion* (newer versions call this completion Cyclic Expand Word).

And of course you can always use `Ctrl + Space`, `Ctrl + Shift + Space`, `Ctrl + Alt + Space`.

Comment: Thianks a lot, it works. Do you know if there are any shortcut keys which can show a "list" like vim

Comment: `Ctrl + Space`, `Ctrl + Shift + Space` and `Ctrl + Alt + Space` are the only I know to show the list of completions.

Comment: Did anyone manage to map `Ctrl + P` to behave the same as `Alt + /`? I added new keyboard shortcut but hitting `Ctrl + P` does not work. There is no conflicting shortcut and I also tried to remove `Alt + /` mapping. No success=(

Comment: @IkarPohorský - It works for me without any problems in the latest EAP of IntelliJ 15.

Comment: Thanks, but I don't think this is an acceptable answer. I've been using vim for over 25 years and use it daily in multiple environments, so having to use 'special' keys for everyday functions, just for this one environment, doesn't make IdeaVIM sound like a good emulator.

Comment: @IkarPohorský Did you finally figure out how to do it?

Comment: @ParthSharma: yup, see the answer from: softw

Answer (score 25):

I could not get CTRL-N and CTRL-P to work after mapping them to "Cyclic Expand Word" and "Cyclic Expand Word (Backward)" in IDEA 2016.2.5 (while running IdeaVIM).  Both keystrokes just did nothing.

The solution was to additionally select "Settings" from the File Menu, then "Other Settings" -> "Vim Emulation", and set the "Handler" for Ctrl+N and Ctrl+P to "IDE" instead of "Vim".

Comment: This is the correct answer for IDEA 2016.3.4. The second part of this answer - changing the handler from vim to ide - is the crucial step, but the keymap for cyclic expand word is also necessary as mentioned in other answers as well as this answer.

Comment: You're a genius.

Comment: @Jason this is precisely **not** the correct answer, as it simply uses keybindings from the IDE and not **Ideavim** as is clearly stated in the question. [Jaysee's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/45109772/16974218) is the correct one, which actually uses Ideavim itself for the mappig.

Comment: @adamency I don't believe the OP is specific on this. The OP asks how to get the keybindings to do code completion, not how to have IdeaVIM do the code completion. I think the idea is that the developer is editing source code and wishes to use those keybindings to complete code and the editor is IdeaVIM - that's all. I don't think the OP cares exactly what happens under the hood as long as the result is correct. Since IntelliJ's keybindings here will search all source in the project and libraries, I believe this is the correct answer.

Comment: However, if the OP really wants Vim behavior of text completion (not code completion) within the current source file only, then you are correct. I just don't see anywhere in the OP that they want text completion within the current source file only. It says "code completion", which generally has the meaning of being across the project and dependencies.

Answer (score 12):

This is the way I found to make the word completion work with CTRL-N and CTRL-P, while still having the shortcuts work for DOWN and UP in lists.

In Settings -> Keymap, map CTRL-N and CTRL-P to Down and Up respectively.
Then, in the Other Settings -> Vim Emulation, set CTRL-N and CTRL-P handlers to Vim.

Finally, add the following to your .ideavimrc

```
imap <C-n> <ESC>:action HippieCompletion<CR>a
imap <C-p> <ESC>:action HippieBackwardCompletion<CR>a
```

Comment: This used to work perfectly. Now after some update of PyCharm/ideaVim (not sure which is the culprit), this doesn't work... It allows hippie completion (aka cyclic expand) but Up/Down in **completion menus** does no longer work.
I tried multiple things but couldn't get both to work again. Any idea how to mkae **both** things work again?

Comment: This is working for me with no other changes (i.e., `<C-p>` and `<C-n>` handler is set to the default Vim). I am using IntelliJ `2020.3.2` and IdealVim `0.64`.

Answer (score 9):

Add the following keymaps: `Ctrl+N` to `Down` and `Ctrl+P` to `Up`

So you can easily navigate in the completions menus.

Comment: That's assuming there _is_ a 'completions' menu. The problem is when we're trying to auto-complete a string, e.g. `MY_ENV_VALUE = os.env["MY_ENV_VALUE"]`. In the real vim, Ctrl+P after the second capital M completes the required string.

Answer (score 5):

File->Settings->Keymap->search keywords "cyclic expand word"

Answer (score 1):

As of IntelliJ IDEA Community Edition v2020.1.1 with IdeaVim v0.57 plugin, what enables me to **auto-complete code as well as cycling through suggestions with with Ctrl+N** is the following:

- File -> Settings -> Keymap
- On the search bar type: hippie
- Add Keyboard Shortcut to "Cyclic Expand Word" Ctrl+N (If prompted, remove other assignments)
- Add Keyboard Shortcut to "Cyclic Expand Word (Backward)" Ctrl+P (If prompted, remove other assignments)

If like me, you had added the following to your .ideavimrc:

```
 imap <C-n> <ESC>:action HippieCompletion<CR>a
 imap <C-p> <ESC>:action HippieBackwardCompletion<CR>a
```

Comment those two lines out by prepending them with ", or delete them.