# PHPStorm ideavim plugin: shell escapes and ctrl-n/ctrl-p completion

Tags: php, vim, phpstorm, ideavim

this is a two-parter.

I am a longtime vi/vim user trying out phpstorm 10. i have the ideavim plugin installed and, generally speaking, it's the best vim emulator i've seen to date. however, there are two issues that i would love to get solutions for.

**1. consistent shell escape behaviour**

shell escaping works sometimes and totally fails other times. for instance:

```
:10,20!sort
```

sorts all the lines between 10 and 20 as expected. however:

```
:10,20!awk '{print $2}'
```

just throws the lines away... is there a way to fix this? i'm very attached to shell escapes.

**2. ctrl-n and ctrl-p completion**

this question was asked previously [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30149091/how-to-configure-in-ideavim-ctrl-n-and-ctrl-p-completion-from-vim), but the answer was wholly unsatisfying (basically "just do something totally different").

i have gone to file->settings->'other settings'->'vim emulation' and set the 'ctrl-N' and 'ctrl-P' handlers to 'vim'... but it does nothing. indeed, ctrl-p and ctrl-n seem completely disabled.

for reference, I am looking for this to behave in a vim-like way if at all possible, ie complete words found in the buffer. for instance:

```
// foobar
foo^p
```

to get 'foobar'.

is this possible? if so, how?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. This is a bug in the implementation of `:!`, feel free to create an issue in the [bug tracker](https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issues/VIM).
2. IdeaVim supports `<C-N>` and `<C-P>` only in the normal mode. You can use PhpStorms' actions for Cyclic Expand Word completion and assign <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>P</kbd> and <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>N</kbd> as shortcuts for them (make sure that these shortcuts are handled by the IDE, not the Vim emulation).